# Android Studio apk working android 9 max but android 10 and 11 showing this erorr anyone have a solution

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kWD5L.png)

App Working 6,7,8,9, But Android 10 And 11 Not Working New Storage Policy Anyone Help You Can Check Code

Comment: Can you add more information like the location of the error and code

Comment: https://github.com/Swati4star/Images-to-PDF/tree/8f6e855e0a339889ec0d6f4f8fab3633cd93bd12    You Can Check This Is Source code . I hope i hope you solve this problem

Comment: Also add the the full error message so no one has to search for where it happens

Comment: Questions should be self-contained. Edit you question and add the full error message(s) as well as the code that's causing the error(s). In text format, not as screenshots.

Comment: Hi , Michael I Hope You Are Good . My problem Is : App Working 6,7,8,9, But Android 10 And 11 Not Working New Storage Policy can you Help me. Check Code
https://github.com/Swati4star/Images-to-PDF/tree/8f6e855e0a339889ec0d6f4f8fab3633cd93bd12

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

For android 10 add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
in your manifest.xml file inside

```
        <application
        android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"  //add this line
       <application/>
```

For android 11 you have to explicitly check version if its less than Build.VERSION_CODES.R then save the picture as you are saving now and in else part you have to create file like this:

```
    File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).getPath(),yourdirectoryname));
```